# How to use regex in PHP to extract a sitemap reference from a robots.txt file?

Tags: php, regex, sitemap, robots.txt

I want to parse a `robots.txt` file and extract the sitemap reference. Assuming that the file is something like this;

```
stuff
foobar
Sitemap: http://www.cgdomestics.co.uk/sitemap.xml
hello world
more stuff
```

I'm trying to use regex to extract exactly this;

```
http://www.cgdomestics.co.uk/sitemap.xml
```

So far I have this PHP code;

```
<?php
  $robots_url = "http://www.cgdomestics.co.uk/robots.txt";
  $robots_file = file_get_contents($robots_url);
  $pattern = "/Sitemap: .*/";
  $i = preg_match($pattern, $robots_file, $match);
  echo $match[0];
?>
```

The output of the above is;

```
Sitemap: http://www.cgdomestics.co.uk/sitemap.xml
```

but I want it to output only;

```
http://www.cgdomestics.co.uk/sitemap.xml
```

Can I use regex to return exactly what I want or do I need to do another step to remove the "Sitemap: " part? Or is there a better way to do this?

As you can probably tell I'm an infrequent user of PHP and regex.

Thanks.

Nigel

Comment: `$pattern = '/Sitemap: (.*)$/m';` and look at `var_dump($match);` after the `preg_match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a sub pattern and grab it from the matches array

```
<?php
  $robots_url = "http://www.cgdomestics.co.uk/robots.txt";
  $robots_file = file_get_contents($robots_url);
  $pattern = "/Sitemap: ([^\r\n]*)/";
  $i = preg_match($pattern, $robots_file, $match);
  echo $match[1];
?>
```

Comment: That returns the string I want except it seems to include a newline at the end which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Use a group (subpattern) for the url, then refer to that subpattern index (1 in this case):

```
  $pattern = "/Sitemap: (.*/)";
  $i = preg_match($pattern, $robots_file, $match);
  echo $match[1]; /*First parenthesized subpattern */
```

From the docs: *$matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern* . See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: +1, you could also use lookbehind to accomplish to only match the address, but that is unnecessary in this case. This is the simplest and most logical way.

Comment: Thanks, that returns the string I want except it seems to have a newline at the end which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/Sitemap: ([^\n]*)\n$/',file_get_contents($url),$matches);

print_r($matches);
```

What does this return for you?

Comment: That returns the string I want but with a newline at the end which I don't want. I don't understand because it looks like your expression specifically excludes newline.

Comment: it matches the \n at the end to be sure it's got it - but if you use trim() on the result, you can strip off the new line character OR you can use preg_replace('/\n/','',$matches[0]); or similar?